# Сумма четных чисел Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Нужно написать программу, которая получает от пользователя число n и выводит на экран значение суммы всех чётных чисел от 1 до n.

Comment: Здравствуйте, в чём именно ваша проблема? Мы подскажем вам решение, если вы покажите, что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: Это как минимум очень легко гуглится.И да, если что то не получается - покажите, что именно :)

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
print(sum(filter(lambda i: i % 2 == 0, range(1, n))))
```

Comment: может лучше так:`print(sum(range(0, n, 2)))`?

Comment: @Danis Ну или так. ;)